# Any way to use a secondary gitlab runner if the primary runner is down?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have set up two gitlab runner instances in two different servers. Is there any way to automatically fallback to the runner in secondary server for a job, if the primary server is down.

I looked into the docs to configure this behaviour, but couldn't find anything useful. Is it even possible?

Comment: If both runners have the same tags. Then the job should be able to run on either of them. It doesn't have a concept of primary and secondary. The workload will be distributed between both as needed

Comment: Created same tags for both runners and it works flawlessly. Thank you.